# Input() in for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm coming to Node.js from Python 3 and wondering if Node.js has something that I can use that is basically the same as Python's `input` for example lets say we have this code:

```
def newUser(user = None, password = None):
    if not user: user = input("New user name: ")
    if not password: password = input("Password: ")
    return "Welcome, your user name is %s and your password is %s" % (user, password)

# Option one
>>> newUser(user = "someone", password = "myPassword") 
'Welcome your user name is someone and your password is myPassword'

# Option Two
>>> newUser()
New User name: someone
Password: myPassword
'Welcome your user name is someone and your password is myPassword'
```

Can node.js do the same thing? If so how? If you have any documentation on it that would be useful also so I can just refer back their if I have any further questions. My main problem though is node.js not waiting for me to submit my reply/answer to the question like python does.

Answer (score 5):

Readline module: http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Here is your example rewritten to Node.js:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("New user name:", function(user) {
    rl.question("New password:", function(password) {
        var newUser = new User(user, password);
        // do something...
        rl.close();
    }
});
```

It looks a little bit different, because the console uses non-blocking IO (like the rest of Node.js and unlike Python).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [prompt](https://github.com/flatiron/prompt) to read input from user.

Sample code:

```
var util = require('util');
var prompt = require('prompt');

// start the prompt
prompt.start();

// text that appears on each prompt
// prompt.message = 'Enter';
// prompt.delimiter = ' → ';

// schema to take user input
var schema = {
  properties: {
    username: {
      message: 'Username',
      required: true
    },

    password: {
      name: "Password",
      required: true
    }
  }
};

function newUser(username, password, callback) {
  if (typeof username === 'function') {
    callback = username;
    username = null;
    password = null;
  }

  var respond = function (err, newuser) {
    callback(null, util.format('Welcome, your user name is %s and your password is %s', newuser.username, newuser.password));
  }
  if (!username && !password) {
    prompt.get(schema, respond);
  } else {
    var newuser = {
      username: username,
      password: password
    };

    respond(null, newuser);
  }
}

/** Test Code --------------------------------------------------------------- */
if (require.main === module) {
  (function () {
    var logcb = function (err, res) {
      console.log(err || res);
    }

    // new user with username and password
    newUser('hello', 'password', function (err, res) {
      logcb(err, res);

      // new user with prompt
      newUser(logcb);
    });
  })();
}
```

Hope this helps, you can make a library routine out of this and use it every time you need to.

Answer (score 1):

[Readline module](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) definitely does the job, as already mentioned. But to get something that looks like `input()` in Python (and avoid numerous callbacks), you can [promisify question method](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/readline.html#rlquestionquery-options-callback):

```
const readline = require('node:readline');
const util = require('node:util');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const question = util.promisify(rl.question).bind(rl);

async function prompt() {
  
    const username = await question('New user name: ');
    const password = await question('New password: ');

    return new User(username, password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the kbd module (https://npmjs.org/package/kbd) is what you need.

This is a little C++ add-on module that make synchronous reading on keyboard.

Comment: you have to explain what that link contains and how that helps . reference can be given after the explaination